# how to set DELL Precision 5530 running Windows 10 to run I7 processor at max speed (4.3GHZ) continually?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, intel-core-i7, dell-precision

Need to run our Intel I7 6core processor at max speed of 4.3GHZ on our Dell Prec 5530 laptop, so that our computation app (compiled by Julia lang) runs continually at max speed 4.3GHZ.

I tried going to bios and disabling Power Mgmt block sleep and Intel speed shift, 
but Windows Task Manager still shows processor speed between 1 and 2 GHz and never 4.3GHZ.   When I run our app, speed gets swings between 2 GHZ AND 4 GHZ.

Answer (score 1):

There is *no* advantage in forcing the CPU to run faster, since it's speed is determined by load. It slows down when there is less demand, e.g. the proprietary app is performing disk I/O, which is *not* CPU intensive. It is also possible the app is not making full use of multi-core CPU's -- independent threads may be blocking each other, for example, over a resource.

You would be better served by setting the customized computation application's *priority* to a higher level. This can be done easily with *Task Manager* or *Process Explorer*, as shown below.

[image: Set Process Priority]

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to open *Task Manager*.
- Right-click on the application process(es).
- Select a higher priority, e.g. *High* or *Above normal*. **N.B.** Setting the process to *Realtime* may make the PC quite unresponsive.